# How can I find specific text in a website's HTML code with Python and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Completely new to HTML and Python here. I am looking to scrape a website with Python to find auction data. I want to find all listings with the text "lb, lbs., pound" et cetera. Here is an example of a listing HTML code I'm interested in:

```
    <a class="product" href="/Item/91150404">
    <div class="title">
                30.00 LB Lego Mini Figures Lego People Grab Bag
                                        <br>Bids: 7                                    </div> </a>
```

I figured out how to get a ResultSet of all the "title" tags with the title_all variable, but I would like to further filter all the auction listings to only show those with "LB" in the name. I have read the BeautifulSoup documentation and the best I've been able to do is return a blank list []. Here is my Python code:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.shopgoodwill.com/Listings?st=&sg=&c=388&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&sbn=false&spo=false&snpo=false&socs=false&sd=false&sca=false&caed=4/18/2020&cadb=7&scs=false&sis=false&col=0&p=1&ps=40&desc=false&ss=0&UseBuyerPrefs=true'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

title_all=soup.findAll(True,class_=['title'])
result=soup.findAll('div', text = re.compile('LB'),attrs = {'class' : 'title'})
print(result)
#does not work
```

I've also tried reading similar questions here and implementing the answers but am getting stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am using Python 3.7.3 and BeautifulSoup 4. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
text=re.compile('LB')
```

Try:

```
string=re.compile('LB')
```

[Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=findall#the-string-argument)

Comment: That one results in an empty list, not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime as dt
import requests

url = 'https://www.shopgoodwill.com/Listings?st=&sg=&c=388&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&sbn=false&spo=false&snpo=false&socs=false&sd=false&sca=false&caed=4/18/2020&cadb=7&scs=false&sis=false&col=0&p=1&ps=40&desc=false&ss=0&UseBuyerPrefs=true'
r = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

# Gathering products.
bs_products = bs.findAll("a", {"class": "product"})

# Gathering listing information for each product.
products = [] 
for product in bs_products:
    price_str = product.find("div", {"class": "price"}).text.strip()
    price_int = int(''.join(filter(lambda i: i.isdigit(), price_str)))
    
    product = {"img": product.find("img", {"class": "lazy-load"}).get("data-src"), 
               "num": int(product.find("div", {"class": "product-number"}).text.split(":")[1]), 
               "title": product.find("div", {"class": "title"}).next_element.strip(),
               "time_left": dt.datetime.strptime(product.find("div", {"class": "timer"}).get("data-countdown"), "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"),
               "price": price_int}
    
    products.append(product)

filter_LB = list(filter(lambda product: "LB" in product['title'], products))
print(filter_LB)
```

Outputs:

```py
[{'img': 'https://sgwproductimages.azureedge.net/109/4-16-2020/56981071672752ssdt-thumb.jpg',
  'num': 91150404,
  'title': '30.00 LB Lego Mini Figures Lego People Grab Bag',
  'time_left': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 21, 19, 20),
  'price': 444500},
 {'img': 'https://sgwproductimages.azureedge.net/5/4-14-2020/814151314749m.er-thumb.jpg',
  'num': 91000111,
  'title': '20 LBS of Bulk Loose Lego Pieces',
  'time_left': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 19, 18, 6),
  'price': 4600}]
```

What I would recommend to do is utilize BS4 for what it is meant to be used -- **scraping** -- and then utilize Python to filter your objects. I won't object to the claim that BS4 *can* filter, but, I've always found that it is best to first implement a general solution, and then deal with specifics in need-be cases.

In case you are not familiar with `filter`, check out the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). If you don't know what `lambda` is, it's a function written in one line. All `filter` does it loop through your objects, and apply the `lambda` function given. Whatever object returns `True` inside the `lambda`, `filter` returns it.

```py
def func(a):
    return a + 2

func(4) # >>> 6

func = lambda a: a + 2

func(4) # >>> 6
```

Happy programming! :)

---

References:

- [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)
- [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)
- [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

---

Edit: For discussion sake below. Say we want to filter the numbers to always be above or equal to 5. We can do it in multiple ways:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

# Traditional filtering way. Makes sense.
filtered_l = []
for i in l:
    if i >= 5:
        filtered_l.append(i)

# Lambda + Filter way
filtered_l = list(filter(lambda i: i >= 5, l))

# Function + Filter Way
def filtering(i): # Notice this function returns either True or False. 
    return i >= 5
filtered_l = list(filter(filtering, l))
```

You might be asking why we do `list(filter())` as opposed to simply `filter()`. That is because `filter` returns an `iterable`, which is not originally a list. It's an [object that you can intereate](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/iterator) through. Therefore, we extract the resources of the `filter` by converting it into a list. Similarly, you can convert a `list` into an iterable (which gives you extra functionality and control):

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
iter_l = iter(l) # >>> <list_iterator object at 0x10aa9ee50>

next(iter_l) # >>> 1
next(iter_l) # >>> 2
next(iter_l) # >>> 3
next(iter_l) # >>> 4
next(iter_l) # >>> 5

next(iter_l)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

You might be asking "why bother using `iter` as oppose to simply using a list?" The answer is because you can overload the `__iter__` and `__next__` functionality in classes to make them into iterable classes (classes you can call for-loops in):

```py
import random

class RandomIterable:
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if random.choice(["go", "go", "stop"]) == "stop":
            raise StopIteration  # signals "the end"
        return 1
```

Which allows us to iterate through the class itself:

```py
for eggs in RandomIterable():
    print(eggs)
```

Or, as you used in `filter`, simply get the list:

```py
list(RandomIterable())
>>> [1]
```

Which in this case, will return you the amount of time (marked by each `1`) that the word `stop` was selected at random. If the return was `[1, 1]`, then `stop` was selected twice consecutively. Of course this is a dumb example, but hopefully now you see how `list`, `filter`, and `lambda` work together to filter lists (a.k.a. iterables) in Python.

Comment: Is lambda used in this case because it's a more efficient/elegant way of incrementing rather than a nested for loop within the outer for loop? Also, perhaps because it's an open ended increment?

Comment: `lambda` was used (in both cases) because the function `filter` takes the parameter `filter(function, iterable)` where `function` is a function that returns `true` or `false`, and iterable is any Python `type` (`list`, `tuple`, etc.) that is iterable via the standard `for i in iterable`.

Comment: So as an example, the following line `filter_LB = list(filter(lambda product: "LB" in product['title'], products))` is equivalent to (replacing `;` with an appropriately indentended new line): `filter_LB = []; for product in product['title']; if "LB" in product:; filter_LB.append(product)`.

Comment: To answer your question more directly, using `filter` and `lambda` is more efficient (in some cases), more elegant, and more Pythonic. You are using the tools given to you by Python to perform your tasks, and not resorting to programming your own filter-like functionality. Hopefully that explains :) Nothing technically or logically wrong with replacing the `lambda`'s with your own code.

Comment: Made edit to explain the conceptuals between `list`, `filter`, and `lambda`.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!

Comment: Yup, my pleasure! :)

Comment: Yes, thank you. Took a few friends making fun of me to realize it - though, their (needed) bullying was after this post.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
# url = 'https://www.shopgoodwill.com/Listings?st=&sg=&c=388&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&sbn=false&spo=false&snpo=false&socs=false&sd=false&sca=false&caed=4/18/2020&cadb=7&scs=false&sis=false&col=0&p=1&ps=40&desc=false&ss=0&UseBuyerPrefs=true'
# html = req.get(url)
# url = 'https://www.shopgoodwill.com/Listings?st=&sg=&c=388&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&sbn=false&spo=false&snpo=false&socs=false&sd=false&sca=false&caed=4/18/2020&cadb=7&scs=false&sis=false&col=0&p=1&ps=40&desc=false&ss=0&UseBuyerPrefs=true'
# html = requests.get(url).text
html = '''
<a class="product" href="/Item/91150404">
    <div class="title">
                30.00 LB Lego Mini Figures Lego People Grab Bag
                                        <br>Bids: 7
    </div>
</a>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
title_all = doc.getElementsByReg('( LB | LBS )',tag="div").text
print(title_all)
```

Result:

```
['30.00 LB Lego Mini Figures Lego People Grab Bag Bids: 7']
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples